# decimal.Decimal(n) % 1 returns InvalidOperation, DivisionImpossible for all n >= 100

Tags: python, django, decimal, python-3.5

I am using Decimal objects in a django app, and found this strange error:

```
ipdb> decimal.Decimal(10) % 1
    Decimal('0')
ipdb> decimal.Decimal(100) % 1
    *** decimal.InvalidOperation: [<class 'decimal.DivisionImpossible'>]
ipdb> decimal.Decimal(150) % 1
    *** decimal.InvalidOperation: [<class 'decimal.DivisionImpossible'>]
ipdb> decimal.Decimal(79) % 1
    Decimal('0')
ipdb> decimal.Decimal(100.1) % 2
    Decimal('0.10')
ipdb> decimal.Decimal(1000) % 2
    *** decimal.InvalidOperation: [<class 'decimal.DivisionImpossible'>]
```

Even more mysteriously, this doesn't happen in ipython until the numbers get very large:

```
In [23]: decimal.Decimal(10**27) % 1
Out[23]: Decimal('0')

In [24]: decimal.Decimal(10**28) % 1
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidOperation                          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-6ceaef82d283> in <module>()
----> 1 decimal.Decimal(10**28) % 1

InvalidOperation: [<class 'decimal.DivisionImpossible'>]
```

Note that the error is not confined to ipdb: I discovered this because Decimal(380) % 1 was breaking my django app.

The [documentation](http://speleotrove.com/decimal/daexcep.html#refexcep) describing this error says:

> Division impossible
>
> This occurs and signals invalid-operation if the integer result of a divide-integer or remainder operation had too many digits (would be longer than precision). The result is [0,qNaN].

Any ideas?

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your error with python 3, works without issue

Comment: I am unable to reproduce in Python 2

Comment: I can repro his last error in Python3.5. `Decimal(10**28) % 1` throws a `decimal.InvalidOperation: [<class 'decimal.DivisionImpossible'>]`

Comment: Check/adjust`decimal.getcontext()`.

Comment: @AdamSmith Same, but that actually fits the error message in the docs

Comment: Reproduced his last error in both 2 and 3.

Comment: You could certainly work around this by doing `try: decimalobj % 1 except decimal.InvalidOperation: int(decimalobj) % 1` since it's only integers that seem to break.

Comment: thank you @StefanPochmann that led me to the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I figured it out.

Looking at the [source code](https://svn.python.org/projects/python/tags/r32/Lib/decimal.py), I found this:

```
# catch most cases of large or small quotient
expdiff = self.adjusted() - other.adjusted()
if expdiff >= context.prec + 1:
    # expdiff >= prec+1 => abs(self/other) > 10**prec
    return context._raise_error(DivisionImpossible)
if expdiff <= -2:
    # expdiff <= -2 => abs(self/other) < 0.1
    ans = self._rescale(ideal_exponent, context.rounding)
    return ans._fix(context)
```

And in my django app, there's an adjustment to the prec:

```
decimal.getcontext().prec = 2
```

This still looks slightly wrong to me, because:

```
In [39]: decimal.getcontext().prec + 1
Out[39]: 3

In [40]: decimal.Decimal(100).adjusted() - decimal.Decimal(0).adjusted()
Out[40]: 2
```

And so it still looks like 100 is within the bounds of what it's checking for (that is, `2 < 3`), but I am pretty confident this is the source of the problem. If anyone can illuminate for me why the library does this, I would love to understand it better.

Comment: I am able to reproduce.

Comment: That's the wrong source you're looking at. The URL looks like it's for 3.2 source. The 3.5 source delegates everything to the [`_decimal` C module](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Modules/_decimal), which is a wrapper around [libmpdec](http://www.bytereef.org/mpdecimal/).